# how can I check whether a scipy distribution is discrete?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

I would like to check whether a `scipy` distribution is discrete or continuous. The test should work whether the object is a frozen distribution object from a named distribution, or an instance of a custom `rv_discrete` or `rv_continuous` distribution.

My first thought was to check the type of the variable, but this does not seem to correspond neatly to continuous vs. discrete. For example, here are four distributions:

```
from scipy.stats import *
import numpy as np

dist_norm = norm(10, 2)
dist_poisson = poisson(10)

class continuous_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, *args):
        if x >= 0 and x <= 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
dist_contin = continuous_gen()

xk = np.arange(7)
pk = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2)
dist_discrete = rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))
```

And here are their types:

```
type(dist_norm)
Out[59]: scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen
type(dist_poisson)
Out[60]: scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen
type(dist_contin)
Out[61]: __main__.continuous_gen
type(dist_discrete)
Out[62]: scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_sample
```

For now I have implemented an `is_discrete()` function by trying to access the `pmf()` method (which only discrete distributions have) but I'm not sure if this is the cleanest or most reliable method. Is there a better way?

```
def is_discrete(dist):
    try:
        _ = dist.pmf(0)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: `except AttributeError:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in function to define custom checks:

```py
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm, rv_discrete, rv_continuous

def is_discrete(dist):

    if hasattr(dist, 'dist'):
        return isinstance(dist.dist, rv_discrete)
    else: return isinstance(dist, rv_discrete)

def is_continuous(dist):

    if hasattr(dist, 'dist'):
        return isinstance(dist.dist, rv_continuous)
    else: return isinstance(dist, rv_continuous)
```

Which will result in:

```py
class continuous_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, *args):
        if x >= 0 and x <= 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
dist_contin = continuous_gen()
dist_poisson = poisson(10)

is_discrete(dist_contin)
#False
is_continuous(dist_contin)
#True
is_discrete(dist_poisson)
#True
is_continuous(dist_poisson)
#False
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I have to first check whether the object is a frozen distribution or a custom distribution. So in my example in the question, I would have to use `isinstance(dist_poisson.dist, rv_discrete)` for `dist_poisson` (which is a frozen distribution) but `isinstance(dist_discrete, rv_discrete)` for `dist_discrete` (which is a custom distribution). So in that case, how can I check whether a distribution is a frozen distribution or a custom distribution?

Comment: Edited my answer introducing a check using `hasattr` function. Hope it helps

Comment: Frozen distributions are instances of rv_frozen